# Profile page: layout breaks with incredibly long location name

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I've just found, that if you enter a really long Location name in your profile settings (and, of course, save it), then go to the Profile page, the location name won't break or display as `...`, and takes up the full available (and not available) place.

This makes the username, title and the description unreadable.

I've also discovered, that this doesn't apply to 'website link', it creates ellipsis (`...`) if very long.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot]

The screenshot was taken on Stack Overflow, but the issue applies to all SE sites, including this one (Meta SE).

Comment: Actually it is possible to trigger this effect on the link/website field. See my ExpressionEngine.SE profile for this: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/9915/mee-was-the-missing-bracket?tab=profile

Comment: @MEEwasthemissingbracket I'd consider that half broken, at least on the mobile site. It just overflows to the right, but doesnt affect the rest of the profile.